# Retrieve hidden field in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to retrieve hidden field in a form for.
Here is my form :

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for :cvs do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :nom, label: "Nom du nouveau CV", :required => true %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :cvuse, :value => params[:user] %>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

When I check my server logs I could see my variable passed :

```
Started POST "/cvs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-31 14:30:36 +0200
Processing by CvsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"someCrazyKey", "cvs"=>{"nom"=>"dd", "cvuse"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save Cvs"}
Unpermitted parameter: cvuse
```

Do you know how I could retrieve this variable `cvuse`. just for precision this form execute the `create` method in my controller.

Comment: add the `cvuse` in your strong param definition..

Comment: allow cvuse using strong parameter than use.

Comment: thank you @dimakura that what I expect. I just replace by `params[:cvs][:cvuse]` Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 3 without strong params:

```
params[:csv][:csvuse]
```

Rails 4 with strong params:

```
def csv_params
  params.require(:csv).permit(:csvuse)
end

def create
  csvuse = csv_params[:csvuse]
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I just want to know : Is there a solution much prettiest than the other?